# jQuery and grails not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails

I have a very simple gsp page that has a button.  I'm trying to use JQuery (Not plugin) to attach to the click event unobtrusively.  However, grails is not giving me any love.  There's

I have this at the very bottom of my main.gsp (after the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have the following code at the bottom of the page that has the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //call out to the controller with the id of this listing and
    //get back a json list of the last several bid amounts
    //
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("got here");
        bindControls();
        //getLatestBids(${listingInstance.id});
    });

</script>
```

and finally, I have this code in my own js file:

```
bindControls= function (){
    alert("clicked me");
    $('#newBidButton').live("click", function(){
        alert("clicked me!");
    });
}
```

I can open chrome and firebug and see that all the js files are loaded.  However, when I click the button nothing happens.   Also, I was expecting the in the  $(document).ready function to fire but it never did.  Anyone with any ideas?

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

Changing my script tag to:

```
    <g:javascript>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            bindControls();
            getLatestBids(${listingInstance.id});
        });
    </g:javascript>
```

and moving my jquery imports into the head tag of the master did the trick.

Comment: Any error? did you step your code in firebug et al? Is jquery loaded before your code? have you got the selector syntax correct? are your script includes before your script tag (i.e. in the header of the html document?)

Comment: No errors.  I get nothing.  No stops.  What do you mean is JQuery loaded before my code?  I don't know much about what grails is doing but I have the script included at the bottom of my main.gsp (as I mentioned in the question).  My scripts are at the bottom of the page.  do they need to be on the top?

Comment: your using which version of Grails? If its Grails 2.0 then Jquery is there already...

Comment: Yes 2.0.  for some reason the <script> tag wasn't working correctly.  I changed it to this: <g:javascript>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            bindControls();
            getLatestBids(${listingInstance.id});
        });
    </g:javascript>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `$` by `jQuery` if you have any conflicting JavaScript libraries on your page. If that's the problem-solver, you can wrap your jQuery code like this:

```
function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
       console.log("got here");
  });
}(jQuery)
```

Comment: Better to use the jquery.noConflict imho but yep